# implement onTouch event in my timerproject

Tags: javascript, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, countdowntimer

I have a timer i want to start when holding down a button,   and reset the timer when i let go.    It was possible with onClick  but i cant really figure out how to use the onTouch event in this projekt. The first code-snippet worked, but how to implement touch instead of click in a asy way?

```
 @Override

    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (!timerHasStarted)
                {
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    timerHasStarted = true;
                    startB.setText("Start");

                }
            else
                {

                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    timerHasStarted = false;
                    startB.setText("RESET");
                }
        }
```

---

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        final float mouseSensitivity = 0.5f;

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            countDownTimer.start();
            timerHasStarted = true;
        } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerHasStarted = false;


        }
        return timerHasStarted; } }
```

---

```
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

       // final float mouseSensitivity = 0.5f;

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            countDownTimer.start();
            timerHasStarted = true;
        } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerHasStarted = false;


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are overriding onTouch by addind the @override annotation, the second implementation sure doesn't, as onTouch always returns boolean.

Make sure you get the touch call and no one else. Set the view's onTouchListener to your object, or extend the View with your own class and implement onTouchEvent

Consider if you need to check that the view is in fact the mentioned button

Also handle MotionEvent.CANCEL, as that happens every now and then and you probably want to do something then. MotionEvent.MOVE can be skipped as you don't want to do anything when that happens.

onTouch should return whether or not it handles the event, NOT the state of your personal timer.